# Python parsing multi column file

Tags: python, parsing, multiline

I have a file where i need to parse and construct in to a single row from multi row using python

```
NAME ID

TITLE DEP

USER1  0023

S1  SALES

USER2  0022

A2  ACCOUNT
```

As you can see here the file header are NAME, ID, TITLE, DEP

I want to print output like below so i can read easy in csv file and do other stuff easily.

```
NAME, ID, TITLE, DEP
USER1,0023,S1,SALES
USER2,0022,A2,ACCOUNT
```

Below is the code i started with but not able to get to where i want.
I tried with different options to split and replace but did not worked.

```
import csv
file =open('test_file_parse.csv','r')
out_file=open('test_out.csv','w')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
for line in lines:
    line=line.strip()
    print (line)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you use something like `sed` to join the pairs of lines first and then process it like a normal delimited file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having all the words in a file called `file.txt` here is the code:

```
# read all the words
with open('file.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().split()

# convert to groups of 4-s
groups4 = [words[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(words), 4)]

# convert to lines with commas using join()
lines = [', '.join(lst) for lst in groups4]

# and here is the result
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
NAME, ID, TITLE, DEP
USER1, 0023, S1, SALES
USER2, 0022, A2, ACCOUNT
```

Comment: Depends on the size of the file. This requires that you can edit the whole thing at once in memory.

Comment: How can you handle blank filed/column in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('test_file_parse.csv','r')
def custom_func(x):
    return next(x).strip().split()
while infile:
    try:
       print ','.join(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, (custom_func(infile) for z in range(4))))
    except TypeError:
       break
infile.close()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this code will solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you know everything will be pairs of two lines and you know you can ignore empty lines, you could do something like:

```
infile = open('test_file_parse.csv', 'r')

# A generator that yields the non-empty lines, without newlines.
lines = (l.strip() for l in infile if l.strip())

# An iterator to iterate over the yielded lines.
line_iter = iter(lines)

# A generator to yield space-separated combined lines.
new_lines = (' '.join(l_pair) for l_pair in zip(line_iter, line_iter))

# Lastly, a generator to yield proper csv for the lines.
csv_lines = (','.join(l.split()) for l in new_lines)

for line in csv_lines:
    print line
```

Comment: Note that since this uses generator comprehensions and an iterator, it should work on arbitrarily large input files without requiring everything to be in memory at once.